# When should I use parentheses in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am a beginner in Knockout and I must say I often get confused regarding when to use `()`. Is there any general tip/trick regarding when would you use `()` against when you would not because at the moment I am just doing trial and error. If the binding throws error or doesn't update values I remove `()` else I put.

Comment: https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/a7c9d9

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You use `()` in knockout when using observables or when executing any other method.
Knockout observables are functions, invoked to return you what you looking for or allow you to assign new values.

In knockout you use `object.property()` to retrieve a value and `object.property(newValue)` to assign a value to that property.

On the knockout [**website**](http://knockoutjs.com/) checkout the documentation, specifically the section on [**observables**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html), which shows you the use of the `()` when querying and writing observables.

To quote:

```
var myViewModel = {
    personName: ko.observable('Bob'),
    personAge: ko.observable(123)
};
```

> - To read the observable’s current value, just call the observable with no parameters. In this example, myViewModel.personName() will
>     return 'Bob', and myViewModel.personAge() will return 123.
> - To write a new value to the observable, call the observable and pass the new value as a parameter. For example, calling
>     myViewModel.personName('Mary') will change the name value to 'Mary'.
> - To write values to multiple observable properties on a model object, you can use chaining syntax. For example,
>     myViewModel.personName('Mary').personAge(50) will change the name
>     value to 'Mary' and the age value to 50.

Knockout's [**interactive tutorial**](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro) is also quite nice and well worth going through.

Answer (score 56):

I feel like the existing answers skip over a very important point of confusion: `data-bind` attributes.

It is true that you use the parens when you are in Javascript, and getting or setting observables. But when you are writing `data-bind="text: property"`, you leave out the parens *even when working with observables*.

## Edit

As noted in the comment below, bindings that are expressions, or access properties of observbles, require parens

```
visible: personName().length > 0
visible: person().Name().length > 0
visible: person().isVisible
```

Note that the last one `person` and `isVisisble` are both observables, but the last property doesn't use parens! The reason for this is that we would be passing a value to the binding instead of an observable, and it wouldn't update.

Comment: Good point, the only exception being if a JavaScript expression is used inside the data-bind attribute, in which case parenthesis **are** required, e.g. `visible: personName().length > 0`

Comment: The parentheses also are required when using comment based virtual bindings, as in: `<!-- ko foreach: observableArray() -->`. I don't understand why this is the case, but as of 2.3.2, it is true.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11318720/1154642 for another example of   using an observable in an expression.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes I don't see how that is at all relevant to the question. Also, if you think a syntax gotcha is enough to ditch an entire library, I don't know how you tolerate React (which I love). `className`? *Sometimes* requiring quotes inside of brackets inside of JSX instead of raw strings? `bind(this)` all over the place? Everybody has some weirdness, it shouldn't be enough to throw the whole thing away!

Comment: I think this link will be helpfull http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/10-things-to-know-about-knockoutjs-on.html

Answer (score 3):

Basically *whenever you're working with an observable value (array or otherwise) you should use the parentheses to get the value and set the value*.

```
var something = ko.obserbable();
something(5); //set value
console.log(something()); //get value: 5
```

The reason being that most JS implementations do not support getters and setters for properties yet, so observables were implemented like this to get around this limitation.