# knockout.js using $index with if binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to show some mark up based on the value of `$index`, I can display the value but I can't seem to use it with an `if` binding, what's the best approach here?

```
<!-- ko if: $index===0 -->
  <div>some mark up here</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

$index is an observable, and observables are functions. When you use observables in an expression you must use the () form to access the value.

```
<!-- ko if: $index() === 0 -->
```

Answer (score 16):

From the [knockout bindings page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

> $index (only available within foreach bindings)
>
> This is the zero-based index of the current array entry being rendered
>   by a foreach binding. Unlike the other binding context properties,
>   $index is an observable and is updated whenever the index of the item
>   changes (e.g., if items are added to or removed from the array).

Example

```
<div data-bind="foreach: details.additionalDetails">
    <!-- ko if: $index() !== 0 -->
        <span> | </span>
     <!-- /ko -->
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span> <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
</div>
```

Results in

```
Model #: UAI5021 | Catalog #: UIOY786
```