# KnockoutJS foreach loop to limit to first array

Tags: knockout.js, foreach

I am using KnockoutJS to render a JSON. Certain results have more than 1 "Applications". Is it possible to make it in the foreach so that it only returns 1 only always? Whichever one comes first.

In example below, TEST1 has 2 results under Applications. I would just like to show one in the rendering.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>AppId</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>App Token</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: APPS, as: 'APP' }">
  <tr data-bind="foreach:  Applications">
    <td><span data-bind="text: appId"></span></td>
    <td><span data-bind="text: $parent.name"></span></td>
    <td><span data-bind="text: AppToken"></span>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**JSON**

```
{
   "APPS":{
      "bad":{
         "Name":"TEST1",
         "Applications":[
            {
               "AppId":"bab",
               "AppToken":null
            },
            {
               "AppId":"bab",
               "AppToken":null
            }
         ]
      },
      "good":{
         "Name":"TEST2",
         "Applications":[
            {
               "AppId":"bab",
               "AppToken":null
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe something like `data-bind="with: Applications[0]"` instead of `foreach`?

Comment: Tried it but doesnt seem to work.  :-(

Comment: Did you get an error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

APPS is not an Array, so you cannot loop through it. Applications is, you can loop through it. But since you want it to be the first item, just use With binding for both APPS and Applications.

Also, correct the case for your bindings in your HTML. Another thing, the Applications array is off of the "good" or "bad" property of "Apps", so you have to qualify it as such.

Here is a fiddle for the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/tyJwX/1

```
<tbody data-bind="with: APPS.bad">
    <tr data-bind="with:  Applications[0]">
        <td><span data-bind="text: AppId"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: $parent.Name"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: AppToken"></span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Only the first binding (`AppId`) in your fiddle is working. Can you update the fiddle so they're all working?

Comment: I wonder why that change made a difference. Seems like both versions should have done the same thing. But +1 for making it work

Comment: Well, yes and no. The first version, the context that was passed in does not know the parent, because when I did this data-bind="with:  bad.Applications[0], there is no $parent. The context does not exist. When I changed it to this with:  Applications[0] and moved bad to the upper level, now I have the context for the parent (which is "bad" property) and hence can now read the "Name" property off of that.

Comment: Right... That makes sense. Can't believe I missed that haha

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I used:

```
<!-- ko if: $index() === 0 -->
```

Got answer from here.
[knockout.js using $index with if binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318441/knockout-js-using-index-with-if-binding)

Comment: don't do that. You will still be looping through the entire Applications. And if you have let say a few 100 of them, you will loop through, do a condition check for every single item. Instead, just use a data-bind="with: bad.Applications[0]"

Comment: This was actually my last resort suggestion if you couldn't get the `with` binding to work. But it was a *last resort* for the exact reason @SujeshArukil just pointed out