# How to append to an existing element in knockout foreach rather than creating new element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

This is a bit of a niche case, but I have a simple chat room style scenario.

So there will be an observable array of chat entries (this will probably be limited to 100 entries which are paged to keep performance good).

So the current foreach looks like:

```
<!-- ko foreach: ChatEntries -->
<div class="chat-entry">
    <img class="entry-sender"></span>
    <span class="entry-content" data-bind="html: Content"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And currently for each entry it will add a new chat entry, which is fine and looks like so:

[image: The existing chat system]

However there is now a requirement to just append to an existing chat entry if the next post is by the same person, like so (forgive horrible paint jobby).

[image: The required chat system]

And I am not sure how to do this in knockout... I was thinking that I could possibly do an afterRender and check if it is the same as the previous entry poster then delete all the created dom and find the previous entry and using jquery or something just append the elements, but this feels very hack-ish as im manipulating the dom manually.

So is there any *good* way to solve this problem?

== EDIT ==

Just to clear up a few things, currently I am always appending to the observable array whenever a new entry comes in, however there is an argument for just re-creating the array every time something new comes in, as this would simplify things quite a bit, but not sure about the visible impact of doing this vs just appending individual entries.

Currently there is like a buffer of 50 after the cutoff point so the main array stores about 100 then will allow another 50% (up to 150 entries) then once it gets over that, it will cut off the last 50 entries and recreate the array, so there is 100 entries again, then the user can page back to see previous entries. so this reduces the recreation but sounds like it may end up getting a bit more complicated. All chat that comes in is stored locally in localstorage so it can be paged quickly without needing the server, so there is not really a worry of *losing* chat data.

Comment: Create a `ko.computed` which works on the `ChatEntries` and does the groupping by the persons name. I've answered something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882964/knockout-generate-for-an-array-of-15-items-3-sections-and-5-articles-for-each-se/17885378#17885378

Comment: So you know, any DOM manipulations aren't rendered until a thread exits.  So unless you using `setTimeout`, that won't be a problem.  There might just be a screen flash if you add/remove elements without proper transitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a few knockout `if` together with the `$index()` function.

Is not the most elegant solutions but it's simple and it does the job.

```
<!-- ko foreach: ChatEntries -->
<div class="chat-entry">
    <!-- ko if: $index() === 0 -->  //first item does not have a previous
        <span class="entry-sender">img</span>
        <span class="entry-content" data-bind="html: Content"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $parent.ChatEntries()[$index()-1]-->    //check if previous is same user
        <!-- ko if: user !== ($parent.ChatEntries()[$index()-1].user)-->    
        <span class="entry-sender">img</span>
        <span class="entry-content" data-bind="html: Content"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: user === ($parent.ChatEntries()[$index()-1].user)-->    
        <span class="entry-content" data-bind="html: Content"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Have a look at the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MaurizioPiccini/yfwFQ/)

This can be done with a computed field also but it require some javascript code and for you to change your model. This solution requiere instead  only changes to the html

Comment: I was looking at doing something *like* this, as I made a method which takes the index and returns a true or a false indicating if the next user is the same as the previous user, the problem is that in your example, much like mine each itteration is going to add a new chat-entry div, and that is going to break it as when the next chat entry comes in, the previous entry will already have been contained as a single entry, so you would somehow have to go back into the previous entry and alter it, which means manual DOM manipulation. This is assuming I am adding to array and never recreating

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't changing array to fit your view be more hack-ish? For manipulating DOM knockout has bindingHandlers. So maybe custom binding would be what you are looking for. Just compare currentUser with previousUser and decide to append span to previous entry or create new one. No jQuery, pure javascript. Or jQuery if you want to do it with effects for new message arrival. You can even provide template as parameter so your chat can have themes for users to choose.

Bindings also has a lot of information already provided: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html

IMO this could be the cleanest solution, data is in model, view is in view. Your main HTML is clean as:

```
<!-- ko foreach: ChatEntries as chatEntry -->
    <div class="chat-entry" data-bind="yourCustomChatBinding: chatEntry"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Just one thought: code above would create empty div if data is appended. KO virtual elements:

```
<!-- ko foreach: ChatEntries as chatEntry -->
    <!-- ko yourCustomChatBinding: chatEntry -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

And virtual elements have some nice API that could be of use: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html

Comment: Depends on how you look at it, as the view model should represent the view, and just be a holding point for the data the view needs. So one could say that the data in the view model should directly represent how the view expects it. However as this is one of those quirky usages which fall outside the norm I would say in this case it would make sense to keep the data as an array as thats what it is, and just somewhere in the view like you say have it represent the data in the different way.

Comment: Good point. Interesting problem you've got here. I will follow this question, maybe I will learn something more.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is a *nice* way, the nicest so far seems to be changing the way the data is stored and recreating the object every time a new message comes in, so a grouped list. Any other possible way seems to have the viewmodel dictating dom usage and playing with stuff it shouldn't do... like you im hoping someone will come and bestow some nugget of knowledge upon us.