# Enable binding: what are the parenthesis for?

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding

There is [a tutorial for DukeScript](https://dukescript.com/getting_started.html), where you need to use Knockout. There is this `enable` binding. Example:

```
<button data-bind="enable: !rotating(), click: $root.turnAnimationOn">Start</button>
<button data-bind="enable: rotating, click: $root.turnAnimationOff">Stop</button>
```

So the DataModel has a `rotating` boolean property.

My questions:

1. Why do we use `()` after `!rotating`?
2. If I remove the parenthesis from the negative form, it won't work. If I add parenthesis to the affirmative form, then it still works. Why is this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use parentheses in knockout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996185/when-should-i-use-parentheses-in-knockout)

Comment: Indeed a duplicate, but the title of it i find a bit too general maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) usually to read a observable we use `()` and we can only perform operations on the `unwrapped` observable content .

As you doing not `!` on observable which is like doing `NOT` on function not on its returned value . so if you want to accomplish this you should `first` read it later apply `NOT` operator on it

2) Point 1 answers your point 2 i.e !(True) is valid but !(function(){}) doesn't looks like a valid case here .

In simple words if you are willing to perform any operations on observable always you should use `()` convention .