# How Knockout JS Declarative Binding internally works

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I have written a code which on the click of a button show or hide a particular div. The code is in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vck80gLf/).
The code is working fine, but my doubt is when i change the value of the observable `a` and `b` on button click, then how come the `toShow` method gets called?

Does it gets called whenever something changes in my '`testViewModel`'? 
Also when do I have to use `()` inside `data-bind`?

HTML Code:

```html
<button data-bind="click: $root.changeValue">Click Me!</button>
 <div data-bind="foreach: products">
   <div data-bind="visible: $root.toShow()">
     <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
     <div data-bind="text: age"></div>
     <div data-bind="text: gender"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function testViewModel(){
   var self = this;
   self.a = ko.observable(0);
   self.b = ko.observable(0);
   var prod = [];
   for(var item in products){
     prod.push(new productItem(products[item]));
   }
   self.products = ko.observableArray(prod);
   self.changeValue = function(){
     self.a(self.a()+1);
     self.b(self.b()+1);
   }
   self.toShow = function(){
    if(self.a() % 2 === 0){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
   }
 }

 function productItem(product){
   var self = this;
   self.name = ko.observable(product.name);
   self.age = ko.observable(product.age);
   self.gender = ko.observable(product.gender);
 }

 var products = [
 {
   name: 'A',
   age: 25,
   gender: 'Male'
 },
 {
   name: 'B',
   age: 27,
   gender: 'Female'
 },
 {
   name: 'C',
   age: 53,
   gender: 'Female'
 },
 {
   name: 'D',
   age: 54,
   gender: 'Male'
 }
]

ko.applyBindings(new testViewModel());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First question**, paraphrased:

> ```
>  <div data-bind="visible: $root.toShow()">...</div>
> ```
>
> ```
>  self.a = ko.observable(0);
>  self.b = ko.observable(0);
>  self.toShow = function(){
>   if(self.a() % 2 === 0){
>     return true;
>   }
>   else{
>     return false;
>   }
>  }
> ```
>
> ...when I change the value of observable `a` or `b` on button click, then how come the `toShow` method gets called?

Whenever you have *any* valid data-bind expression in your view, Knockout will upon first evaluation register a dependency tree to track which `observable` (incl. observable arrays, etc) affects the value of the data-bind expression. It does so for binding to plain observables, but also for functions like the one you have.

This means `data-bind="visible: $root.toShow()` will make Knockout see upon first evaluation that it is dependent on `a` (but *not* on `b`!), and whenever `a` changes it'll re-evaluate the `visible` binding.

**Second question**:

> ...when do I have to use `()` inside data-bind?

This has already been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10996185/419956), though the answers aren't very complete currently IMHO. Know these two things:

1. An observable is a *function*, and invoking it without arguments *gets* its current value.
2. Knockout will "magically" add those parentheses if it sees an observable name as the only thing in a data-bind expression.

So it's *always* safe and optional to do `myObservable()` inside a data-bind, and you can *sometimes* (e.g. when the observable name is the only bit of the expression) leave off the parentheses.

**P.S.**:

Your question title asks "how it internally works", so note that Knockout is [open source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout) and you can have a look at [e.g. the expression rewriting](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/expressionRewriting.js) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In your example toShow will be triggered only once, when the view will be render. To make knockout to track dependencies you have to make this as computed

```
<code>
self.toShow = ko.computed(function(){
    var x = self.a();
    if(x % 2 === 0){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
});
</code>
```

Take a notice that I have get the value observable a before the if statment - this is for make sure that knockout track this dependency in this compute always. Because in your example if it goes to else branch there won't be any longer dependency to a.

As for second question: brackets are not needed for computed and observables. Simple functions have to have them.